# How do artificial neural networks store data compared to biological neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, biology

Do scientists know by what mechanism biological brains/biological neural networks store data?

I only have a vague notion that we store data in our brains by altering synapses.

I also would love a decent description of how a vanilla artificial neural network stores data.

So, my 2 questions are

1. How is data stored in a biological neural network?
2. How is data stored in an artificial neural network?

Answer (score 7):

Second question first: Data is stored in an ANN in the form of weights in the adjacency matrix between neurons. During training, these weights are updated by a learning algorithm (such as [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)).

First question: according to award-winning neuroscientist Tim Bliss:

> “It’s been accepted really since the turn of the 20th century, since the time of the Spanish neuroscientist Ramón y Cajal, that really the only place where memories can be stored is at synapses, the junctions between nerve cells.

A protein called the NMDA receptor plays a key roll in the strengthening of synaptic connections (which is more broadly achieved by a form of [Hebbian Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebbian_theory)).